# How to get the raw 'created_at' value in the database (not an object cast to an ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, time, format

Imagine I have a Post Model.

and one record in the database will be:

```
23|title_here|content_here|2011-02-20 08:01:55.583222|2011-02-20 08:01:55.583222
```

and the last two field (`2011-02-20 08:01:55.583222|2011-02-20 08:01:55.583222`  ) are the created_at and updated_at field.

Then,

```
post = Post.find_by_id(23)
```

**Question**: How can I get the created_at string: "`2011-02-20 08:01:55.583222`" in the data base?

As we know, the post.created_at will return a `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` object, not the raw string.

Please help :)

Comment: You may simplify the find call to  `Post.find(23)`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

use [attributes_before_type_cast](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/BeforeTypeCast.html)

```
Post.find(23).attributes_before_type_cast["created_at"]
```

or

```
Post.find(23).read_attribute_before_type_cast("created_at")
```

**Edit**

You can call like this also:

```
Post.find(23).created_at_before_type_cast
```

according to [Accessing attributes before they have been typecasted](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html).

Comment: First solution works also with reading data that is serialized

Comment: There you go, congratz 5 digits @rubyprince

Comment: @rubyprince I'm sorry but SO is smarter than us and revoked my votes. Anyway 5 digits are coming very soon!

Answer (score -7):

Try

```
Post.find_by_id(23).created_at.to_s
```

Comment: This will get something like this :"2011-02-12 09:10:32 UTC". But what I want is "2011-02-20 08:01:55.583222" witch contains millisecond info.

Comment: This will yield the datetime without the millisecond info.