# Rails: always include the milliseconds with created_at for every model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, model

How do I modify my Rails app to always include the milliseconds information with the `created_at` field of my models?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056447/how-to-get-the-raw-created-at-value-in-the-database-not-an-object-cast-to-an-a) has the answer for how to do it for an individual model, but I want to do it globally.

---

For example, when I retrieve all my `Item` models (by hitting `/items` with a GET), I get the following JSON:

```
[{"created_at":"2011-08-07T23:42:15Z","updated_at":"2011-08-07T23:42:15Z","id":180,"user_id":6,"content":"test"}]
```

But note that the `created_at` field doesn't have any information about the millisecond that it was created. How do I include that for all my models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to override the `created_at` attribute selector for my Item model using [this guide](http://betterexplained.com/articles/intermediate-rails-understanding-models-views-and-controllers/).

Anyone know how to do it for all models?

Comment: Create an abstract model that inherits from ActiveModel and have all your models inherit from it, or put it in a library module and require/include it everywhere you need it.

Answer (score 26):

For Rails 4.1 and above you can set the [time_precision](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActiveSupport/JSON/Encoding#time_precision-class_method), e.g. in application.rb

```
ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.time_precision = 3
```

By the way, showing the milliseconds is now the default, it can be set to 0 if they should be omitted.
Also it's good to know that `.iso8601` doesn't include milliseconds but `.as_json` preserves them.

Comment: 3: `"2017-03-20T00:06:21.685-07:00"`, 1: `"2017-03-20T00:06:21.6-07:00"`, 0: `"2017-03-20T00:06:21-07:00"`

Answer (score 4):

Overriding `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone#as_json` worked for me:

```
class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone

  def as_json(options = nil)
    if ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.use_standard_json_time_format
      xmlschema(3)
    else
      %(#{time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")} #{formatted_offset(false)})
    end
  end

end
```

Make sure to put this code in a file that is required by your Rails app. Now when I convert a created_at attribute to JSON, I get the milliseconds:

```
puts Post.last.created_at.to_json
# => "2012-06-29T11:51:00.841Z"
```

Also make sure to use `Time.zone` to instantiate new Time objects so that they show the same JSON behavior:

```
time = Time.zone.now
puts time.to_json
# => "2012-06-29T16:45:30.547Z"
```

Hope this helps someone!