# Rails ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone as_json date format issue

Tags: datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm producing an API in rails, where some of the responses include a date. 
In my database, the fields are setup as datetime fields, which rails then turns into `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` objects. When I respond to a request with a datetime in, I expect to get something like

```
2013-07-23T01:18:32Z
```

But instead, I'm getting

```
2013-07-23T01:18:32.000Z
```

Why is there the additional `.000` at the end? As right now this is breaking the code on the client I'm writing. Obviously I could fix the client by changing the format it is expecting, but I'd like to know why rails is doing this in the first place, as the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/as_json) suggests it shouldn't have the `.000` there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it's a change in Rails 4

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb#L157

Seems the API docs need updating :(

Answer (score 9):

For others coming here from Google. There is a related question with a more up to date answer for Rails 4.1+ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27474221/242426).

The precision for JSON encoding of time is now configurable. According to the [Rails upgrade guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#json-representation-of-time-objects) you can now add the following line in an initializer instead of monkey-patching:

```
ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.time_precision = 3
```

Comment: Simple and very precisely. By default in Rails 4.1+ time_precision is set to 3. And in previous versions WHERE THIS OPTION DOES NOT EXISTS it uses 0 for default time precision.

Comment: And you can set `time_precision = 6` to make this true: `t = Time.current; t == Time.zone.parse(t.as_json)`. Otherwise `t.usec` will be different after serialize/deserialize. Tested with rails 5.1

Answer (score 7):

If you want to revert to the format without the milliseconds, you can add an initializer with the following code:

```
    class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
    #Changing the as_json method to remove the milliseconds from TimeWithZone to_json result (just like in Rails 3)
        def as_json(options = {})
            if ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.use_standard_json_time_format
                xmlschema
            else
                %(#{time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")} #{formatted_offset(false)})
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: I'm curious what "good" indentation looks like in RoR. All I have ever seen is people complaining about when it's bad.

Answer (score 6):

i had same issue recently.

and I found the commit log. 
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9128

Comment: Nice find :) Always annoying when things get changed and break stuff

Answer (score 0):

this might work as well

```
# With ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.use_standard_json_time_format = true
Time.utc(2005,2,1,15,15,10).in_time_zone("Hawaii").to_json
# => "2005-02-01T05:15:10.000-10:00"

# With ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.use_standard_json_time_format = false
Time.utc(2005,2,1,15,15,10).in_time_zone("Hawaii").to_json
# => "2005/02/01 05:15:10 -1000"
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-as_json

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your application configuration:

```
config.active_support.time_precision = 0
```

Or set the number to whatever you want.