# Ruby on rails created_at column is not showing up in my deserialized model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

end
```

In my database I can see that my created posts are getting a `created_at` and `updated_at` column set to the correct times.  I want to display this value to the user, but created_at is not included in my deserialized object in my response. How can I make sure this value is included in my response so I can display it to my user?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056447/how-to-get-the-raw-created-at-value-in-the-database-not-an-object-cast-to-an

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [Attribute Methods Before Type Cast](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/BeforeTypeCast.html)

But this could be applied on single active record object, not on array of active record objects

Comment: What is the correct way to do this on an array of active record objects?  Just loop through each one of them.  Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: As per my knowledge, you have to loop through each one.